# How to resolve this problem " near "INSERT": syntax error" in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I cannot find what wrong in my code, but it is showing  "sqlite near "`INSERT`": syntax error".

my code is

```
/*CREATE TABLE Employee
    (
      Emp_ID varchar not NULL PRIMARY key, --0/""
      Emp_Name Varchar,
      Location varchar,
      commission INT,
      phone_no varchar,
      country varchar
      );
*/

INSERT into Employee VALUES ("1","rachit","MP","1700","1234567898","india")
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("2","Swapnil","UP","1524","3485030230","india")
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("3","Hardik","MH","1469","5684586954","india")
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("4","Sarthi","GOA","1985","4995406905","india")
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("5","Rupak","KT","1654","9040938640","india")
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("6","soham","UK","1598","9894945932","india")
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("7","palash","NCR","1789","8984647458","india")
```

Comment: String literals should be in **single** quotes - `'NCR'` - not double quotes ...

Comment: Add `;` at the end of each INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add `;` at the end of each insert statement.
The correct syntax would be

```
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("1","rachit","MP","1700","1234567898","india");
INSERT into Employee VALUES ("2","Swapnil","UP","1524","3485030230","india");
```

Comment: In SQLite there is no problem if INT values are enclosed in double quotes. Also it is not standard practice to use BigInt for primary keys. Who upvoted this?